# Plotting the sum of series

Tags: matlab, plot, matlab-figure, matlab-guide

I use this code and i don't know what it needs to work for my problem:

```
    syms x k t
    for t=0:10
    num=((-1)^k)/k
    t1=sin(8*3.1415*k*t)
    S1=symsum((num*t1),k,1,2);
    x=0.5-((1/3.1415)*S1);
    end
 Plot(x)
```

[image]

On the x axis I show time and on the y axis I show the function over four periods.

When I try to run the code I get the following error:

> Undefined function 'symsum' for input arguments of type 'double'.

Maybe I can't use symsum with my argument type, but is there another function I can use? Sum also didn't work:

> Error using sum Dimension argument must be a positive integer scalar within indexing range.

Comment: Does N=2 in the equation so that the `symsum` ranges from 1 to 2?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you want to plot `x(t)`, you need to use `plot(t,x)` where `t` and `x` are vectors.

Instead of using `for t=0:10`, just let `t=0:10` and calculate the corresponding `x`.

Also, the symbolic variable is just `k`.

```
syms k 
t=0:10;
num=((-1)^k)/k;
t1=sin(8*3.1415*k*t);
S1=symsum((num*t1),k,1,2); 
x=0.5-((1/3.1415)*S1); 

plot(t,x)
```

It is noted that if you let `t=0:10`, then the `sin(8*k*pi*t)` will always be 0 since `t` is a vector of the integer from 0 to 10. The result of `x(t)` will be 5:

Output when `t=0:10`:
[image]

As you can see, the value of `x(t)` is very close to each other. Theoretically, they should all be 5. But there is some numerical approximation which leads to the small error.

You probably want non-integer `t`. Here is a output when `t=0:0.1:10`
[image]